# Update page after bean value has changed

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

I am trying to restrict the rendering of a PrimeFaces tab depending on whether a user is an admin or not.

I am using the following EL to do so:

```
<p:tab title="Admin" rendered="#{userSession.isAdmin}">
```

My UserSession class:

```
@ManagedBean(name="userSession")
@SessionScoped

public class UserSession {
    .
    .
    .
    public boolean isAdmin;

    public UserSession() {
         isAdmin = false;
    }

    public void addRole(String role) {
        if (role.equals("ADMIN") {
            this.isAdmin = true;
        }

        role.add(role)
    }
}
```

The addRole() method gets called and adds the role "ADMIN". I know this isn't a good way of doing things, but I'm only using it for testing purposes at the moment.

My issue is, is that the tab is not being rendered because isAdmin is recognised as false in the constructor. If I change the constructor to true, then it does render.

How can I make it so that is will recognise isAdmin is true afterwards? i.e. after the ADMIN role has been given to the user's session?

Is it possible to 'reload' the page so it can refetch the 'isAdmin' property after it changes?

Comment: call addRole() with ajax request and update your tab.

Comment: @ShadyAziz is the ajax request necessary? Surely if you update the tab it will be able to 'see' that it has changed?

Comment: yes, it is. Think about the principale here. You want to call a function in the backend and then update a certain module in your UI to render it or not.

I suggest you read about it in prime faces. here is a simple example

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/basic.xhtml

Comment: what i got by question, you want to reload page after role change to admin, it can be happen by back bean when role == admin update page in if condition otherwise do not update the page. in ajax is not mandatory to update or reload page, you can update page only in if condition.

Answer (score 1):

You could update any Primefaces Component using [RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.0/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html) at your ManagedBean methods. For instance in your case at `UserSession.addRole(...)` method.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("ID_OF_YOUR_TABVIEW")
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I am looking for, but still isn't working as I am expecting it to. What exactly do you mean by using it 'at ManagedBean'?